# How to retrieve a KeyValuePair from a function call?

Tags: c#, keyvaluepair

I'm building a function that returns two parameters. I learned that this can be achieved with

```
    KeyValuePair<string, int> ExtractGroup(string s, int offset, int TagLength)
    {
    .. 
    return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(part, startIndex);
    }
```

But how do I assign the returned value when I call this function back to the 2 variables?

```
string GetPart = ExtractGroup(data.ToString(), 0 , data.ToString().Length)[1]
string GetIndex = ExtractGroup(data.ToString(), 0 , data.ToString().Length)[2]
```

I've been trying and googling for more than 2 hours and just can't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `KeyValuePair<,>` has a `.Key` and a `.Value`, so:

```
var pair = ExtractGroup(data.ToString(), 0 , data.ToString().Length);
var part = pair.Key;
var startIndex = pair.Value;
```

The same would be true of `Tuple<,>`, except it would be `.Item1` and `.Item2`.

Comment: Great! Thank you... it's kind of frustrating to see that my question has been rated as "This question does not show any research effort; its unclear or not useful". I spent 2 hours with this. As an autodidact you sometimes stumble over problems that takes hours to solve. If you know the answer then it's always easy...